# MySQL show empty or null table columns

Tags: mysql

I have a quite big table and I want to find out which columns are unused (either empty or NULL for all rows). Is there an easy way to do that either with a query or with phpMyAdmin?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using sum() on each field in your table. The value will be 'null' for field which has only null values.

```
select sum(id), sum(name), sum(field1), sum(field2) from play_table
```

Comment: These only works if the constraint for that column is a numeric field. You cannot do a sum of a column that is text

Comment: That's right, you'll not get correct result of SUM() but it's not needed. You only need to see which is NULL.

Comment: won't a SUM on a string column just fail.

Answer (score 1):

For a string column

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN column is null or COALESCE(LTRIM(RTRIM(column)),'') = ''
                THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS ZERO_IF_COLUMN_IS_ALL_NULL
FROM TABLE
```

For a numeric column

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN column is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS ZERO_IF_COLUMN_IS_ALL_NULL
FROM TABLE
```

Yes you have to do it for each column, but you can do multiple of these in a single select statement.

Comment: Thanks for this late answer! I'll try that!

Comment: Wow, I just realized how old this question was -- glad you were still around

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY column
```

Then you can see which values inhabit `column` in which number.

Comment: I'd need to run that for each column separately, right? (which is not what I aim)

Comment: Yes, indeed, you have to decide which column to check.

Comment: This does not check for empty strings

Answer (score -1):

This should work, not tested though.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'my_table'
AND column_default is  null;
```

Comment: What should I be looking at to find out which are empty/null?

Comment: This shows which columns have a default of null.  he wants all values in the table are null.

Answer (score -1):

```
SHOW columns from "TableName";
```

The above commands display columns of the empty table and also its respective properties
{ex: Name having varchar(50) or int AUTO_INCREMENT (Primary Key)}

Comment: Have you tried running your answer on a MySQL table? If not please do try, it will give you an error (version 5.7). To list table details you can use either `DESCRIBE tableName` or `SHOW COLUMNS FROM tableName`

Comment: thanks for pointing the error, at the place of show, mistakely have written select

Answer (score -2):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_empty()
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
           CONCAT('(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM Table1 WHERE `', 
                  column_name, '` IS NULL ',
                  CASE  
                    WHEN data_type IN('varchar', 'char') 
                      THEN CONCAT('OR `', column_name, '` = ''''')
                    WHEN data_type IN('date', 'datetime', 'time') 
                      THEN CONCAT('OR `', column_name, '` = 0')
                    ELSE ''
                  END, ')`', column_name, '`'))
     INTO @sql
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   WHERE table_schema = SCHEMA()
     AND table_name = 'table1'
     AND column_name NOT IN ('id')
   GROUP BY table_name;

  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql);

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;


to use this, which separate your null columns
```

Comment: The query executes fine but gives me no output.